# Understanding the relation between minor and the rank of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A \in F^{nxn}$ be a matrix and the determinant of each minor is $0$. 
Prove that $rank(A) \leq (n-2)$.

Could anyone explain why this is true? I know that if the determinant is 0 then the matrix is not invertible. So I can say that $rank(A) < n$ but why is it less than $n-2$?

Comment: What are the orders of the minors here?

Comment: @user326159 I'm not sure if i understand the question, but I think $n-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a matrix $m\times n$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $0<k\leq \min\{m,n\}$. We define a minor of order $k$ of $A$, denoted as $\Delta_k$, as the determinant of a matrix $k\times k$ that results by the elimination of $m-k$ rows and $n-k$.

Also, we know that a number $r$ is said to be the rank of a matrix if it satisfies these two conditions:

$\square$ There is at least one minor of order $r$ that not vanishes.

$\square$ Every minor of order $r+1$ or higher vanishes.

Now, we get back to the problem. If all the $(n-1)-$order minors vanish, then the determinant vanishes. Indeed, we can express the determinant for some constants $c_i$ as
$$\det(A)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \Delta_k^i=0$$
since $\Delta_k^i=0$.
Now, the rank just can be $n-2$ or lower since

$\square$ Every minor of order $(n-2)+1=n-1$ or higher (the determinant of the matrix) vanishes.

$\square$ If there are minors that not vanishes, they are from order $n-2$ or lower because we are told that all $n-1$ and $n$ order vanishes.

Comment: Why isn't the the rank $0$ than? if all $n-1$ minors vanish, doesn't it mean that all $n-2$ minors have produce $0$ from their determinant?

Comment: If all the minors or order $n-1$ vanish, it does not imply that the ones of order $n-2$ vanish. To see it, just consider the matrix formed by the vectors $(1,1,1)$, $(2,2,2)$ and $(3,3,3)$. All the minors of order $2$ will vanish, but the minors of order $1$, that are the entries of the matrix, does not.