# Prove that the singular matrices form a hypersurface

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

I have to prove that the set of singular $n\times n$ matrices forms a hypersurface in $K^{n^2}$ and describe what happens with matrices of rank $n-1$.

I need to do this from an algebraic point of view. I know that a hypersurface is a set of solutions to a single equation $f(x_1,...x_n)=0$ and that singular matrices are not invertible and have a determinant  equal to $0$. But I don't know how to bring these two concepts together.

Comment: $\det(A) = 0$ is a single homogeneous polynomial equation in $n^2$ variables. For example, when $n=2$, it is $x_{11}x_{22}- x_{21}x_{12}=0$. It cuts out precisely the set of singular matrices in $\mathsf{Mat}(n,F)$.

Comment: @Pedro Thanks a lot. What about the part "describe the set of matrices of rank < n-1"? What would there be to describe?

Comment: @Annalisa One can characterize the rank of a matrix by the vanishing of its minors. For the precise result, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3646148/22912).